# xsd - not allowing values defined in the enumeration list

Tags: xsd, schema

I would like to enforce a rule on the attribute which should not allow a value defined in enumeration values associated with another attribute.

Here is my sample schema.

```
<xs:complexType name="component">
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="componentMainType"/>
    <xs:attribute name="category" type="forbiddenCategoryTypes" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="forbiddenCategoryTypes">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    **<xs:pattern value="not in forbiddenCategoryTypes"/>**
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="componentMainType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Component1"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Component2"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Component3"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Component4"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Component5"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion not possible, pattern only takes a regex. I could not find any other relevant restriction.

I would suggest to change approach to regex with values (I know it is not optimal solution).